# Any assumption in the RISC-V ISA preventing the stack from growing up rather than down?

Tags: assembly, riscv, stack-memory, stack-pointer

I was wondering whether anything in the ISA would make a stack growing up (a push increases sp, a pop decreases it) less performant or otherwise inadvisable? I am aware that this is not how present day tooling works, including Linux and GCC ports, but is there any fundamental reason beyond "it would be an insane amount of work"?

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two reasons why it would be problematic beyond only being a lot of work for software to change.

The first is about RISC V: the compressed instructions are designed to store into the stack at positive offsets having a range of `sp+0` to `sp+252` (in multiples of 4), rather expecting a descending stack: accessing sp+N where N>=0, which is allocated stack memory, either simple items pushed on the stack one by one, or the whole stack frame of a function.  With an ascending stack, sp+N where N>=4 is free stack memory that we generally wouldn't have any desire to access, so you'd loose the compressed instruction loads & stores for memory-based local variables & parameters.

The second is a practical matter rather than a RISC V issue: when using an ascending stack, the stack pointer refers to the end of the item that is on the top of the stack.  We normally refer to memory objects by their first & lowest address.
  When varying size items are place onto an ascending stack, then the address of the item on the top of the stack, in terms of an offset from `sp` changes depending on the item's size — this doesn't happen with a descending stack.

Other than the above, such as regarding performance, I don't think the hardware would care.

Comment: I don't think that second item is a problem at all; addressing memory relative to a frame pointer pointing to the top of a stack frame is also a normal thing in code with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, and in that case the offset includes the size of the object.  (At least on most ISAs; IDK where RISC-V convention normally points a frame pointer if you have one.)  Object sizes are always known at compile/assemble time, unless you have VLAs in which case things are more complicated in multiple ways and compilers usually keep a pointer to the VLA.

Answer (score 1):

It might be as easy as flipping a bit in the microcode to add instead of subtract from sp.

The fundamental reasons I can think of are

- Inertia. Why would you want to when it requires changes to each toolchain?
- Installed base. A lot of code may make assumptions in which direction the stack grows. You need a very good reason to break existing code.
- Complexity. With allocations from the heap growing towards higher addresses, do you also want to turn this around to keep heap and stack growing towards each other?

Comment: RISC-V doesn't have hardware `push` / `pop` instruction; software has to do it with `sub` or `add`, and `sw`/`lw`.  (And is pretty big on philosophical RISC purity, aimed at a design with no microcode, I think.)  That's the main point of this question, whether software could use an upward-growing stack on actual current RISC-V chips, without the CPU having to know about it.  (Normally you wouldn't use sub/sw pairs at all, of course, just one sub to move SP and then multiple stores and reloads.)